# How to renew security certificates in java control panel in java 6

Tags: java, security, digital-signature, digital-certificate

When I'm looking on the java control panel, the security certificate has been expired.

[image]

Os is Windows server 2008.
I'm getting the '`signjar certificate has expired`' warning during the java application installation. Is this warning is related to the security certificate expiry?

How can I renew this security certificate?

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty likely that if they used a different certificate, that they also used a different key pair. I.e., if you installed an updated certificate, your the signature over the .jar would not verify anymore.

It's a warning. And it is an important one, Java 6 support has ended eons ago. Especially if you use security related applications, please upgrade to 7 or 8. If *some* care has been taken within the applications, they should not just run, they should run *better* on 7 and 8.

Comment: What is the significance of this certificate expiry?

Comment: Must have forgotten that in the last few months or so.